# Using nodejs fs module within my meteor app

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I need to read some json file and then load the data into the db. Instead of using HTTP I want to use fs module from node.js. The question is that how can I use the following code from within meteor app.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var file = __dirname + '/test.json';

    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
         console.log('Error: ' + err);
         return;
    }

    data = JSON.parse(data);

    console.dir(data);
});
```

Comment: Or you could use the [assets api](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/assets_getText) as described [here](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/get-text).

Answer (score 3):

If you are within a package, then all you need to do is to replace the `require` with `NPM.require`:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
```

If you want to use it in a project (not in a package), then just add the `meteorhacks:npm` to your project and then use

```
var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer...Where is this kind of information documented?

Comment: You should probably mention that `Npm.require` is only available in packages.

Comment: @MikeC: Yes, good point. I've updated the answer to show how to do it when not in a package, too.

Comment: `Npm.require('fs')` seems to work anywhere on the server (at least it does in 1.2.1). I have now idea when that changed, as I can't find the corresponding issue or entry in the change log.

Answer (score 0):

Or go the more Meteor way, so your code could begin with:

```
var data = Assets.getText('/test.json');
EJSON.parse(data);
```