# using fs module in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, fs

I want to read data out of a file and into a Mongo collection in Meteor.

I installed meteorhacks:npm as suggested in this post:

[Using nodejs fs module within my meteor app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21420147/using-nodejs-fs-module-within-my-meteor-app)

But I get this error message when I click on the button that runs my fs code:

Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.npmRequire is not a function

I did some looking around and ended up finding this link which recommended several steps for using fs under Meteor 1.2:

http://info.meteor.com/blog/announcing-meteor-1.2

So I upgraded to Meteor 1.2 and then followed these steps:

rm -rf packages/npm-container
meteor remove npm-container
meteor update meteorhacks:npm
meteor

I am getting the same error.

I'm new to Meteor and JS, but I have prior experience with Perl and PHP. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me to get past this bottleneck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that answer is outdated. You should be able to `Npm.require('fs')` anywhere on the server. The alternate answer using the assets api is actually better, if you can put the files under your `private` directory.

Comment: Thanks, David. When I try that, I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: Npm is not defined". (This code is in my client code, by the way.) 

Would I need to declare or instantiate Npm somewhere before being able to run the 'require' method?

Comment: Npm is not available on the client. You cannot use the file I/O on the client anyway. If you wish to send the relevant sections of npm modules to the client side, you can use [browserify](https://atmospherejs.com/cosmos/browserify) or, as a more radical approach, [webpack](https://medium.com/@SamCorcos/meteor-webpack-from-the-ground-up-f123288c7b75#.ov0ej9xy6).

Comment: I finally got smart and moved the actual file reading code into the server area. The fact is, I don't need to be able to do it from the client. I was just focused on trying to get it to work before figuring out other details.

Comment: Now that I've got it in the right place, I'm still getting errors. I seem to have gotten past the error relating to the 'require' reference. Here's what I'm actually seeing:

Comment: I20151130-13:25:27.063(-7)? { [Error: ENOENT, open 'C:\Users\David\LaunchCode\test\test\.meteor\local\build\programs\server\anglo-25Lines.txt']
I20151130-13:25:27.063(-7)?   errno: 34,
I20151130-13:25:27.063(-7)?   code: 'ENOENT',
I20151130-13:25:27.064(-7)?   path: 'C:\\Users\\David\\LaunchCode\\test\\test\\.meteor\\local\\build\\programs\\server\\anglo-25Lines.txt' }

Comment: I have not been able to figure out how to put a break tag or equivalent in these comments, so I apologize for the wrapping of the four-line error message above.

Comment: One last comment: When I saw the path error, I put my input file into the directory in hopes that it would see it there. Interestingly, meteor keeps erasing it from the directory.

Comment: I have it in the regular 'server' directory, as well, and also right in the main root directory for the project. But it doesn't seem to want to look for it in either of those places.